# OpenCV match template without mask?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two images:

Left: key.png, right: frame.png

[image: Key.png]
[image: Frame.png]

Both images have size: 200x157.

And i have some probles when applying for that `cv2.matchTemplate`

```
cv2.matchTemplate(cv2.imread('frame.png'), cv2.imread('key.png'), cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
array([[ 0.86354846]], dtype=float32)
```

Why i have result 0.863 when it's not a similar images? Can anybody explain me behavior of this function and suggest how to fix it or another way?

in 90% of cases it is working properly but not here... Why?

**Note:** I can't use feature detection and detection actually because i need find similarity of really visually similar images;

**UPDATE:**

For those people who think that everything is good right:

[image: key.png]
[image: frame.png]

```
>>> cv2.matchTemplate(cv2.imread('frame.png'), cv2.imread('key.png'), cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
array([[ 0.90551066]], dtype=float32)
```

Image subtraction:

[image: subtraction]

Image difference:

[image: difference]

Ok, for my comparison i need image subtraction algorythm like as in Photoshop and GIMP for analysis different point quantity.

**UPDATE:**

I'm trying to release the function getMSSIM in python, but results isn't perfect:

```
def calcMssim(i1, i2):
C1 = 6.5025
C2 = 58.5225

d = cv2.CV_32F
I1 = numpy.float32(i1)
I2 = numpy.float32(i2)

I1_2 = cv2.multiply(I1, I1)
I2_2 = cv2.multiply(I2, I2)
I1_I2 = cv2.multiply(I1, I2)

mu1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(I1, (11,11), 1.5)
mu2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(I2, (11,11), 1.5)

mu1_2 = cv2.multiply(mu1, mu1)
mu2_2 = cv2.multiply(mu2, mu2)
mu1_mu2 = cv2.multiply(mu1, mu2)

sigma1_2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(I1_2, (11,11), 1.5)
sigma1_2 = sigma1_2 - mu1_2
sigma2_2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(I2_2, (11,11), 1.5)
sigma2_2 = sigma2_2 - mu2_2
sigma12 = cv2.GaussianBlur(I1_I2, (11,11), 1.5)
sigma12 = sigma12 - mu1_mu2

t1 = 2 * mu1_mu2 + C1
t2 = 2 * sigma12 + C2
t3 = cv2.multiply(t1, t2)

t1 = mu1_2 + mu2_2 + C1
t2 = sigma1_2 + sigma2_2 + C2
t1 = cv2.multiply(t1, t2)

ssim_map = cv2.divide(t3, t1)

return cv2.mean( ssim_map )
```

Results:

example #1

[image: уbz]
[image: fy7]

```
./mssim.py yBZzJ_e.png Fy7Xu_m.png 
 (0.8257484750741396, 0.7267644621469662, 0.7066612513808068, 0.0)
```

Match k ~ 0.74
First image more lighten that second.

example #2

[image: Key.png]
[image: Frame.png]

```
./mssim.py key.png frame.png
(0.7317456233025181, 0.7624613566388057, 0.7645396253480031, 0.0)
```

Match k ~ 0.75
First image and second is really visually different!

**PSNR comparison:**

```
    def calcPSNR(I1, I2):
        s1 = cv2.absdiff(I1, I2)
        s1 = numpy.float32(s1)
        s1 = cv2.multiply(s1, s1)

        s = cv2.sumElems(s1)
        sse = s[0] + s[1] + s[2]

        if (sse <= 1e-10):
             return 0
        else:
             mse = sse/(len(I1.shape) * I1.shape[0]*I1.shape[1])
             psnr = 10*math.log((255*255)/mse, 10)
             return psnr
```

Results is:

example 1:

```
   ./psnr.py yBZzJ_e.png Fy7Xu_m.png 
   26.4697468901
```

example 2:

```
   ./psnr.py key.png frame.png
   15.4679854768
```

it's not correct too because:
       ./psnr.py key.png key.png
       0

Comment: The images do not look that different to me; most pixels of the first image are a homogenous off-white, and most pixels of the second image are a homogenous light-blue, so kinda similar rgb values and structure. The black bars at the top and bottom are identical. Is the value of 0.863 that far off from other images? keeping in mind a value of 1 would mean all pixels match perfectly, and a value of 0 would mean all pixels are as different as possible. (btw. in my limited tests I found TM_SQDIFF_NORMED gave me the best results (with 1 and 0 swapped))

Comment: Unfortunately, you're wrong. If you compare histograms and trying to do substraction in photoshop you can sight a difference. Shapes and contours of images are different too.

Comment: I'm sorry! I've misunderstood you...Maybe you should try to crop the image edge and TV show logo from image...

Comment: Even the human eye sees frame.png have more blue than key.png (which have more white). @G M, it is useless, I have tried :-(

Comment: @xercool sure there are visible differences, which is why the value returned by matchTemplate is not 1. But why are you certain that that the value 0.863 is due to a bug, and not due to the fact that both images are kinda similar? If you match a pure black image and a pure white image, I'd expect the value to be 0; for a grey image and a white image, I'd guess it would be 0.5; so for a mostly white and mostly light-blue image, both with black bars, 0.86 does not sound that far off. Do you have other images that are more similar to each other but score lower?

Comment: no, no and no again.. They are different. The reason #1: rms are really different, the color tints are different, objects on images are different.. I attach now to my question subtraction result to show you.

Answer (score 1):

did you take a look at PSNR?
This calculates the difference of each pixel of your images.
For further information and an OpenCV example read: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#videoinputpsnrmssim

Comment: I will try to release that.

Comment: I had translated getSSIM algorythm. Results isn't perfect. He can't ignore brightness level change on both images.

Comment: See my updated question. I had write my code and provide examples.

Comment: sorry, i'm update images for example #1.. So... now you can look differences.

Comment: Did you try the PSNR? I 've got good result with it. For better results you could compare your color layers separately.

Comment: So i have calculated MSSIM. Is there is any difference if he uses the results MSSIM? I do not quite understand how to analyze the results of PSNR (what i will to do with the results in 'decibels', but not percents of matches/dismatches)...

Comment: The 'decibels' are the pseudo unit for the formula after "Then the PSNR is expressed as:" in the link above. 
I guess in your second example you will get a value about 20dB.
In the first example with different brightness you should get a value >> 20dB.
Thread the returning value in dB as matches. The higher the more similar your pictures are. 
You should maybe learn, what a good threshold could be. Just try it with a few pairs of pictures.

Comment: Is not correct behavior for my situation. I've get on identical value is 0, example 1 is 26.4697468901 and example 2 is 15.4679854768. That's not correct for my question and idea. Brightness example must have value lower than emample with white-blue/white image...

Comment: Then take the MSE-Value, if the images are equal you will get 0.